# Can you install & boot linux from a specified folder?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

The Situation:
I have access to a computer in the university, but no root rights. I already installed Ubuntu on a USB Drive and I could boot and run Ubuntu, but the computer has only USB 2.0 and I'm not happy with the speed, so could I install Ubuntu on the hard disk, but in my home folder?

Could I then put just a bootloader on the usb drive, which knows the special location of Ubuntu?

EDIT: The computer runs a linux distro.

Comment: [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Comment: Thanks! But the PC is running linux and not windows :(

Comment: What's the point in getting root access?  have you tried going about it the proper way (asking)?  If so did they give you a reason for turning you down?

Comment: The point is, to be able to install software I want/need.

Comment: 1) If feasible, you  can ask the Administrator to install Virtualbox for you and you can install Ubuntu in a virtual Hard drive inside your said folder. There will be huge performance cut if the machine isn't good with specs. 2) Otherwise, I once encountered (couldn't find now) the idea of installing Linux in a virtual hard disk (opposed to virtualization). You may look about this idea. This [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/) might be bit helpful.

Comment: Thanks Firelord, that's exactly going in the direction I was looking for.